# Edit Users from Admin account

Tags: php, mysql

I have been playing around with editing user profiles (Logged in as) which is working just fine.

So I decided to try editing other users profiles by populating a table with users (which works fine and also has, ban & delete working fine), clicking a hyperlink with id (which works fine), showing the username of the profile and their current profile info(which works fine) and a form to update which is identical to the edit session user form(also, works fine).

But when submitting, it does not update the record.

I am using `$userID = $_GET['id'];` and also binding that to sql select id command.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once '../includes/conn.php';

if(!$user->is_loggedin()){
    $user->redirect('../users/login.php');
}

$userID = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$userID));

$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $location = isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : null;
    $about = isset($_POST['about']) ? $_POST['about'] : null;
    $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : null;

    $sql_part = array();
    $prepare = array();
    if ($location) {
        $sql_part[] = 'location = :location';
        $prepare[':location'] = $location;
    }
    if ($about) {
        $sql_part[] = 'about = :about';
        $prepare[':about'] = $about;
    }
    if ($title) {
        $sql_part[] = 'title = :title';
        $prepare[':title'] = $title;
    }
    $prepare[':id'] = $userID;

    if (count($sql_part)) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET ';
        $sql .= implode(', ', $sql_part);
        $sql .= ' WHERE id = :id';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if ($stmt) {
            $result = $stmt->execute($prepare);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            header('Location: '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <title>EpicOwl UK | CMS Users Edit Profile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" src="../images/logo.png" /></a>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <a href="../index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="./profile.php"><li>My Profile</li></a>
            <a href="../admin/index.php"><li>Admin Panel</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
<form method="post"><br />
    <h2>Edit <?php echo ($userRow['username']); ?>'s Profile</h2>
    <label><strong>User Title:</strong></label><br />
    <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo ($userRow['title']); ?>" /><br /><br />
    <label><strong>My Location:</strong></label><br />
    <input type="text" name="location" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo ($userRow['location']); ?>" /><br /><br />
    <label><strong>About Me:</strong><label><br />
    <textarea name="about" rows="13" cols="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="<?php echo ($userRow['about']); ?>"></textarea><br /><br />
    <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button><br /><br /><br />
</form>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p class="copyright">&copy; EpicOwl UK. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just notices I was trying to post submit, but it should have been update.  Which now makes it update the row, but only my logged in row when tried on other accounts.  Question edited.

Comment: You are using `placeholder`, to post the variables you need the `value` attribute (for the textarea; `<textarea>$value</textarea>`, does this help?

Comment: This does not but would work I think to replace the placehokders.  Somehow the above change made it work for all usrrs... Maybe I didn't upload the edit first time or something.